# How to get different selected values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone how can I get two values from different select boxes? I get first value in my select box but I can't get the second value from another select box.Here is my javascript code:

```
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
              var select = document.forms[0].sel;
              var select2=document.forms[0].sel2;
              select.onchange = function () {
                  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; // to get Value
               alert(value);

              }
               select2.onchange = function () {
                  var value2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value; // to get Value
               alert(value2);

              }

          });

        </script>

 <form>
<SELECT NAME="sel" onChange="split(selected value)">
<OPTION VALUE=1>Milk</option>
<OPTION VALUE=2>tea</option>
<OPTION VALUE=3>water</option>
<OPTION VALUE=4>coffee</option>
</SELECT>
</form>

 <form>
<SELECT NAME="sel2" onChange="split(selected value)">
<OPTION VALUE=1>Milk</option>
<OPTION VALUE=2>tea</option>
<OPTION VALUE=3>water</option>
<OPTION VALUE=4>coffee</option>
</SELECT>
</form>
```

Comment: added jQuery but coded with Regular JS code.Why two different form?

Comment: `forms[0].sel2` is invalid. `sel2` resides within `forms[1]`. Also, please learn to write your tags in lower case

Comment: I think you should start, by one select, and practice how to get the value using jQuery because you have mixed techniques. Is very simple problem and you can fix it yourself. But if you didn't practice more simple things you never will learn to do this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second select box is in the second form. So:

```
var select2 = document.forms[1].sel2;
```

That said, you can actually use jQuery for these things:

```
// bind a change event handler to the second select
$("select").eq(1).on("change", function() {
  alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Tip - Getting Select List Values](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-select-list-values)

```
var foo = []; 
    $('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
      foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#sel').change(function(){ $('#sel option:selected').val();  });
```

give id to your select control

```
<SELECT id="sel">
```

Answer (score 1):

with help of jQuery ( i suggest the logic, not the solution )

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){    
   var selecetdOption = $(this).val();
          alert(selecetdOption );    
});​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzxbg/)

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong into your javascript because you have put

```
var select2=document.forms[0].sel2;
```

try to put

```
 var select2=document.forms[1].sel2;
```

and it works!